# Deducing x86 Assembly Code

Tags: assembly

I have some Assembly code, and am basically trying to figure out what it does. I ran disassem in gdb to come up with this:

```
Dump of assembler code for function Q5bomb:
   0x08048454 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048455 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048457 <+3>: sub    $0x28,%esp
   0x0804845a <+6>: cmpl   $0x0,0x8(%ebp)
   0x0804845e <+10>:    je     0x80484bb <Q5bomb+103>
   0x08048460 <+12>:    movb   $0x61,-0x12(%ebp)
   0x08048464 <+16>:    movb   $0x7a,-0x11(%ebp)
   0x08048468 <+20>:    movl   $0x0,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x0804846f <+27>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048472 <+30>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048475 <+33>:    jmp    0x8048495 <Q5bomb+65>
   0x08048477 <+35>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804847a <+38>:    movzbl (%eax),%eax
   0x0804847d <+41>:    cmp    -0x12(%ebp),%al
   0x08048480 <+44>:    jl     0x80484be <Q5bomb+106>
   0x08048482 <+46>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048485 <+49>:    movzbl (%eax),%eax
   0x08048488 <+52>:    cmp    -0x11(%ebp),%al
   0x0804848b <+55>:    jg     0x80484c1 <Q5bomb+109>
   0x0804848d <+57>:    addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048491 <+61>:    addl   $0x1,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x08048495 <+65>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048498 <+68>:    movzbl (%eax),%eax
   0x0804849b <+71>:    test   %al,%al
   0x0804849d <+73>:    jne    0x8048477 <Q5bomb+35>
   0x0804849f <+75>:    cmpl   $0x13,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x080484a3 <+79>:    jle    0x80484c4 <Q5bomb+112>
   0x080484a5 <+81>:    mov    $0x80485ce,%eax
   0x080484aa <+86>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   0x080484ad <+89>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
   0x080484b1 <+93>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x080484b4 <+96>:    call   0x8048330 <printf@plt>
   0x080484b9 <+101>:   jmp    0x80484cf <Q5bomb+123> //skips segfault
   0x080484bb <+103>:   nop
   0x080484bc <+104>:   jmp    0x80484c5 <Q5bomb+113>
   0x080484be <+106>:   nop
   0x080484bf <+107>:   jmp    0x80484c5 <Q5bomb+113>
   0x080484c1 <+109>:   nop
   0x080484c2 <+110>:   jmp    0x80484c5 <Q5bomb+113>
   0x080484c4 <+112>:   nop
   0x080484c5 <+113>:   mov    $0x0,%eax //segfaults the code
   0x080484ca <+118>:   mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x080484cc <+120>:   mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x080484cf <+123>:   leave  
   0x080484d0 <+124>:   ret    
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
End of assembler dump.
```

Now, I'm new to Assembly in general, and don't expect to know what every single command does. However, the program itself takes a string input, and seems to segfault unless you input some sort of correct string. Armed with that knowledge, I'm basically trying to find what a "correct string" would look like.

From what I've gathered, 113, 118, and 120 throw a seg fault into the code (this was tested experimentally with stepi). The only way to bypass that is to somehow get to 101, which jumps over the segfault and returns a value.

Additionally, 12 seems to add "a" as a local variable, and 16 adds "z" as a local variable. 57 seems to shave the first character off of your input.

Line 71, where test %al %al is called, seems to be critical to the program in some way. Every input string that I feed in ends up failing that test and jne-ing back to 35, where it seems doomed to lose the first char of the string and go through the process again and again, until you're left with nothing but "" and the program crashes again.

Can someone explain to me what that critical line 71 is doing, or offer any insight into how this code as a whole functions?

Comment: `test al,al` is an optimized way of saying `cmp al, 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will segfault in the following cases

- The argument is a null pointer. A pointer to a ASCIIZ string is expected.
- The string contains anything else than lowercase letters
- The string is shorter than 20 characters.

The line at <+71> finds out if the end of the string was reached. It could have been written like `cmp $0x0,%al` but many assembly language programmers would prefer to use `test %al,%al`. The result is the same.

```
0x0804849b <+71>:    test   %al,%al
```